# what is wrong in my code that i got "Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch" error

Tags: matlab

Why in below codes I get this error:"

> Subscripted Assignment Dimension Mismatch".

I want to make a vector that its components are `u1_1` and `u1_2`. and in the third nesting `for` I tried to write `u1` as a vector but I got above error, what is wrong?

```
clc
clear all
close all
a=3e-2;
E0=0.1;
z=0.42;
L=z;
N=200;
lambda=1030e-9;
k=2*pi/lambda;
w0=0.001;
zr=pi*w0^2/lambda;
R=z*(1+(zr/z)^2);
w=w0*sqrt(1+(z/zr)^2);
D=linspace(-a/2,a/2,N);
[xx,yy]=meshgrid(linspace(-a/2,a/2,N));

for i=1:N
    for j=1:N
        x=xx(i,j);
        y=yy(i,j);
        [teta,r,z] = cart2pol(x,y,z);
        u1_1(i,j)=E0*sqrt((r.^2)./w.^2).*exp(-(r.^2)./w.^2)*(cos(teta));
    end
end

for i=1:N
    for j=1:N
        x=xx(i,j);
        y=yy(i,j);
        [teta,r,z] = cart2pol(x,y,z);
        u1_2(i,j)=E0*sqrt((r.^2)./w.^2).*exp(-(r.^2)./w.^2)*(sin(teta));
    end
end

for i=1:N
    for j=1:N
       x=xx(i,j);
       y=yy(i,j);
       [teta,r,z] = cart2pol(x,y,z);
      u1(i,j)= [u1_1
          -u1_2];
    end
end
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, unfortunately your question is ill formed. To remedy this you should ***edit*** to add: (a) show EXACTLY at which line the error occurs, if it's in a loop then check the state (size and values) of the variables used in that line; (b) write out the FULL ENTIRE error message verbatim as it appears in Maltab; (c) Cut down any unecessary code (i.e. anything that comes after the loop with the error maybe?), code that does not pertain directly to understanding your error and (d) explain what your code is trying to do! Please make sure you do this for ALL future questions as well.

Answer (score 0):

That's because `u1_1` and `u1_2` are matrices of dimensions `N`x`N` and `u1(i,j)` is a scalar. Can you see the problem of saying `scalar = matrix`?

In fact, that last `for` loop is completely unnecessary, you can replace it with a single line:

```
u1 = [u1_1
      -u1_2];
```

This will construct `u1` not as a vector, but as a matrix of dimensions `2*N` x `N`.

Now, if you want `u1` to be simply `u1_1 - u1_2`, you need:

```
u1 = u1_1 - u1_2;
```

In that case, `u1` is a matrix of dimension `N`x`N`. It's not clear from your question what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Two problems with your code:

```
u1(i,j)= [u1_1
      -u1_2];
```

First: no subscripts for u1_1 and u1_2
Second: declaring array around u1_1 and u1_2. This makes the rhs as 1x2 matrix.

Solution:

```
u1(i,j)=u1_1(i,j)-u1_2(i,j);
```

Answer (score 0):

yes you're right.
code's error is occurred in line 41. I wrote 'for' loop for 
" u1(i,j)= [u1_1-u1_2];" because after make u1 (vector with u1_1 and u1_2 components), I am going to use from "Trapz"command to propagate the u1 beam and when I used "u1 = [u1_1 -u1_2];", I got a 1*200 array and its shape is a 2D. in fact, I want to its be 3D.
I think I can describe what I want!